# call a method inside the same class

Tags: java

Can someone please explain why this is not working?
can you not run a method that belongs to the same class?
I have been going at this for a while and my brain is just starting to hurt.
Thank you in advance.

My error im getting is "Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dProb (wrong name:DProb)" its not a compile error though. its when i try to pass the variables.

```
public class DProb{
    public static double Combinations(long N, long X){
        double comb = 0.0;
        long n = N;
        long r = X;
        long denom;
        if(n==r || r == 0)
            n = 1;
        else{
            denom = n-r;
            for(long i = n; i > denom; i--){
                if (i == n){}
                else
                    n *= i;
            }
            for (long i = r; i > 0; i--){
                if (i == r){}
                else
                    r *= i;
            }
            n = n/r;
        }
        comb = n;
        return comb;
    }

    public static double HyperGeometric(long Np, long Xp, long N, long X){
        double probX = 0.0;
        double leftNum = Combinations(N,X);

        return probX;
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling a method in the same class would work fine. What error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: Did you mean "not working" instead of "now working"?  (P.S. that's a very common typo.)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I compile this.  If it's throwing an exception or giving you the wrong results, please clarify.

Comment: Seems there is no error in your code, could you please give the error which you are getting

Comment: my error im getting is "Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dProb (wrong name:DProb)"
its not a compile error though. its when i try to pass the variables.

Comment: Where are you referring to "dProb"?  Can you post that code too, since that's probably where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling from you main function make sure the Class name is right.

As per your Error it seems Your Class name is having issue.

Your class name is **DProb** and you are typing dProb.

Also why are you returning 0.0 in  HyperGeometric as you Probx variable is 0.0..

Comment: omg i feel stupid, yes i was running my command wrong.... no problem here, dont mind me! and the method is not finished. thats why its returning a 0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DProb{
```

needs to be

```
public class dProb{
```

The most likely reason for this is your .java file is called dProb.java. The class name and file name must match!

Comment: The brackets are fine.

Comment: its hard to tell i guess, the start brackets are really bunched up